# Comparing yesterday's data with today's data

Tags: sql, apache-spark, parquet, databricks

I have 2 parquet tables, one for today and one for yesterday. What I want to do is compare what has changed in today's table, e.g.:

- which new rows have been added
- which rows have been deleted and when they have been deleted
- which rows have been changed

The tables itself have columns "createdAt" and "updatedAt" which I can use for this purpose.

I'm working with Databricks/Apache Spark so I can either use their built-in functions or an SQL query. I'm not sure how to go about this, any general ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maintain one audit table behind your main table. data must be inserted in Audit table when you perform Insert, update or delete on your main table. Audit table should include createdAt of main table and current date-stamp.
If you manage transaction-type Insert, update or delete with 1,2,3 then it will be good for Query performance.

Comment: I did that and the main problem here is that it isn't performant enough. With about 2 million rows per table I was more trying to use Apache Spark's dataframe capabilities to solve this.

Comment: 2 million rows per table is not much count, please check index over table using Execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know the LoadType (full or delta) for your table, I will try to cover both the  scenarios:-

***Full Load*** - 
For this, you only need today's table as it will contain all the previous days record as well.
Hence you only need to put condition to check all the records that are modified after yesterday's load using **updatedAt** column i.e 
updatedAt > yesterday's load date

***Delta Load*** - 
For delta, each day you will get modified records(new, updated or deleted) only, hence just query today's table without any condition will serve the purpose.

Now, on spark side, as you have large number of records, you can manipulate number of dataframe partitions at runtime using something like below:-

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 1500");
```

please find other optimization techniques here
https://deepsense.ai/optimize-spark-with-distribute-by-and-cluster-by/